# C# Como fazer aplicativo publicado utilizar as configurações que alterei no app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, framework, console-application

Tenho um aplicativo do tipo Console NetFramework, e tenho nele o app.config.

Meu aplicativo precisa utilizar as tags do **app.config** que altero com frequência para gerar alguns arquivos de texto, ou seja tenho informações que são dinâmicas ali.. porem em modo debug quando altero as informações do app.config ele reconhece e gera os arquivos normalmente. Quando o aplicativo está publicado ele considera as informações do app.config de modo **"Congelado"**

Como fazer meu aplicativo publicado considerar o App.CONFIG com esses dados dinamicos?

Comment: Se você precisa de variáveis dinâmicas talvez seja melhor você pensar em outra estratégia, como armazenar essas informações em um banco de dados ou outro arquivo de texto, como um json por exemplo. A sua aplicação só vai ler o app.config no startup, logo, toda vez que você alterar algum valor vai ter que reiniciar a aplicação, para que a mudança tenha algum efeito.

Comment: Apresente o código de como você está alterando e recuperando essas variáveis do app.config

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionado, acredito que seja melhor pensar em outra estratégia, pois app.config são [arquivos de configurações](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/config-builder).

Mas por toda via, você deve executar o método [ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_RefreshSection_System_String_) para que os valores sejam lidos novamente.